# A good source for the proof of the Levy-Khintchine formula

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Im looking for a good source of a proof of a 1 dimensional version of the Levy-Khintchine formula. I have looked everywhere but no luck so far. I would appreciate any help.
Here is the specific version i would like to find a proof of:

The probability measure $\mu$ on the real line is infinitely divisible with characteristic exponent $\Phi$ if and only if there exists a triple $(a, \sigma, \Pi)$, where $a, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Pi$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ satisfying $\int_{\mathbb{R}}1 \wedge x^2 \Pi(dx)\leq \infty$, such that for every $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the following holds:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\theta x} \mu(dx) = e^{-\Phi(\theta)},\ \text{for} \ \theta \in \mathbb{R},
$$
and
$$
\Phi(\theta) = i a \theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\theta^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1 - e^{i\theta x} + i\theta x 1_{(|x|<1)})\Pi(dx).
$$
Furthermore, the triple $(a, \sigma, \Pi)$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Durrett suggests Breimann 1968, Section 9.5, or Feller, vol II (1971), Section XVII.2. I have no idea what they are like. I find Durrett impenetrable at times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @copper.hat. I will check them out and post my thoughts when done.

Comment: So far i have checked out Breiman's probability book, but I haven't seen any mention of the Levy-Khintchine formula?

Comment: Bummer. I was just quoting directly from Durrett. Good luck.